Gradle composite builds - How to make an included task depend on a task in the project including the build?
I have a Gradle project that includes a number of other builds. Making a task in the root project depend on a task in one of the included builds is easy:
tasks.register("run") {
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("my-app").task(":app:run"))
}

But I can't find a way to do the opposite. Is it really not possible to tell Gradle that a task in the included project depends on or at least should run after a task in the root project?

That functionality would not be expected, no. It's very much not designed that way: an included build is meant be fully built itself before its outputs are used to help with the main build.
More generally, in most cases adding explicit mustRunAfter or dependsOn relationships are signs that you may be doing it wrong. Ideally, you want to chain tasks and projects together using their outputs since task-only relationships are brittle1 and don't give Gradle the all the information it needs to know what tasks it needs to run for a given build invocation.
Maybe you would like to share what you are trying to do more generally to help you consider an alternative approach.

1For example, see task configuration documentation

You are probably right. It feels a bit like I'm trying to force a square peg into a round hole. I'll see if I can change structure this in a different way.

Could it be that Gradle won't detect task dependencies based on outputs across different builds in a composite build? If I add several tasks inside a single build that all declare the same file as an output Gradle forces them to run in sequence, but doing the same thing with tasks in different builds does not produce that effect.

Indeed yes there is no such linkage between tasks between an included and a main build. The approach you need is to produce an appropriate outgoing artifact from an included build using variant-aware matching and then you can pick it up with a project dependency in the dependencies block. Perhaps you might like to ask a separate question with a more concrete example
